# Try replacing the keyword with a return type

Tags: dart, flutter

After upgrading Dart to 2.3, I'm starting to get this error:

```
file:///Users/user1/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/graphql_flutter-0.9.5/lib/src/widgets/subscription.dart:13:3: Error: Function-typed parameters can't specify 'const', 'final' or 'var' in place of a return type.
Try replacing the keyword with a return type.
  final dynamic error,
  ^^^^^
```

in this code:

```
typedef SubscriptionBuilder = Widget Function({
  final bool loading,
  final dynamic payload,
  final dynamic error,
});
```

How do I fix it? I can't find any documentation around this on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to clean cache with this command "flutter clean"?

Comment: just tried. didn't help.

Comment: interestingly, upgrading graphql_flutter to 1.0.0 fixed the problem.

Comment: great that you solved the issue :)